# R1C1 Code does not quite work

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

i am trying to write into certain cells within a Loop with variables in the formula.

The relevant line Looks like this:

```
Worksheets("Judaspriest").Cells(p, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(G" & Cut & ":G" & p & ")"
```

In the Sheet though the formula within the cells reads:

```
=SUMME('G2':'G109')
```

How can I get rid of the ' '.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `.FormulaR1C1` part because you are not using **R1C1** references but **A1**.

Let's check how look the references on the same cells:

- A1 References:  B1, C5, G9
- R1C1 References: R1C2, R5C3, R9C7

In R1C1 you can have absolute references to cells like the examples above. In addition you can use relative references. They are relative to the active cell so you can have things like `R[1]C[2]` that means 1 row down and 2 columns to the right of the active cell.

A sheet in A1 looks like this:

[image]

A sheet in R1C1 looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So just .Formula or nothing at all?

Comment: Your formula is using A1. If the sheet columns are `A,B,C,D`.... then your sheet is also using A1. If the sheet columns are `1,2,3,4` then the sheet is using R1C1.

Comment: thank you very much bermu, especially for the Edits that clarified everything. Have a nice day